# Need help using pandas to covert a url into a dataframe for college basketball data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get barttorvik.com data into a dataframe. I can scrape  with the following code, but I get an error when trying to export the dataframe into excel.

I am assuming the error has to do with the header row on the site's table. I am unsure how to modify the imported data to make it exportable. Any help would be appreciated and thank you in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
url = 'https://www.barttorvik.com/#'
df = pd.read_html(url)
df.to_excel('/outputdestination', index=False)
```

This is the error I get after running the code

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'to_excel'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html. It returns a list of Dataframes.

```
df[0].to_excel('./outputdestination', index=False)
```

Comment: Does this then leave me with a multi-level index? Do have a recommendation for how to remove the first row of the index?

Comment: perhaps I didn't ask this correctly. I now  need to drop the first row and first column of the new dataframe. Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: @Pmannn The feature ``index=False`` to drop the first column is still not implemented when exporting to excel, you'll need to find a workaround. You can still drop the first row by passing the argument ``header=False``.

Comment: One last thing, for purposes of working with the dataframe python, how would I drop the first row and column so I am only left with 'Rk', 'Team', 'Conf',....

Comment: If I understood correctly your question, you can do ``df[0].columns = df[0].columns.droplevel()``

Comment: @Pmannn `df = pd.read_html(url, header=1)[0]` to drop that level header

Comment: @Pmannn then do `df = df[df.ne('Rk')]` to ket rid of those extra header rows